# Show that the energy of the electromagnetic field is given by half the norm of the Fourier transform of the electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation

Following Peskin and Schroeder on page 179-180, I am trying to show that

$$\frac 12\int d^3x \left(|\mathbf E(x)|^2+|\mathbf B(x)|^2\right) = \int \frac{d^3 k}{(2\pi)^3}|\mathbf k|^2\sum_{\lambda = 1,2}|\mathbf \epsilon_\lambda(\mathbf k)\cdot\mathcal A(\mathbf k)|^2,$$

but I have three questions.

First, how do we lift the ambiguity in the imaginary parts of $\mathcal E(\mathbf k)$ and $\mathcal B(\mathbf k)$? On page 179, they are defined so that the real parts of their Fourier transforms give the electric and magnetic fields (equation (6.8))

$$\begin{aligned} \mathbf E(x) &= \operatorname{Re}\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\mathcal E(\mathbf k)e^{-ik\cdot x}|_{k^0=|\mathbf k|}\\
\mathbf B(x) &= \operatorname{Re}\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\mathcal B(\mathbf k)e^{-ik\cdot x}|_{k^0=|\mathbf k|},\end{aligned}$$

but inverting the first equation gives

$$2\int \mathbf E(x) e^{-i\mathbf{k’}\cdot\mathbf x} d^3x = \mathcal E(\mathbf{k’})e^{-i|\mathbf k’|x^0} + \mathcal E^*(-\mathbf{k’})e^{i|\mathbf k’|x^0}.$$

Do we use that $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ satisfy Laplace’s equation to complete them to analytic functions before inverting the Fourier transform?

My second question is about showing that

$$\mathcal E(\mathbf k)\cdot\mathcal E(-\mathbf k) + \mathcal B(\mathbf k)\cdot\mathcal B(-\mathbf k) = 0,$$

Using

$$\begin{aligned} \mathcal E(\mathbf k) &= -i\mathbf k \mathcal A^0 + ik^0\mathcal A(\mathbf k)\\
\mathcal B(x) &= \hat k \times \mathcal E(\mathbf k)\end{aligned}$$

and transversality of the electric field ($\mathbf k \cdot\mathcal E(\mathbf k) = 0$), I obtained

$$\begin{aligned}\mathcal E(\mathbf k)\cdot\mathcal E(-\mathbf k) &= -(k^0)^2\mathcal A(\mathbf k)\cdot\mathcal A(-\mathbf k) + |\mathbf k|^2\mathcal A^0(\mathbf k)\mathcal A^0(-\mathbf k)\\
\mathcal B(\mathbf k)\cdot\mathcal B(-\mathbf k) &= |\mathbf k|^2\mathcal A(k)\cdot\mathcal A(-\mathbf k) - \left(\mathbf k \cdot\mathcal A(\mathbf k)\right)\left(\mathbf k \cdot\mathcal A(-\mathbf k)\right),\end{aligned}$$

but I couldn’t show that these two quantities sum to zero.

My last question is how to use transversality of the electric field to obtain

$$\sum_{\lambda = 1,2}|\mathbf \epsilon_\lambda(\mathbf k)\cdot\mathcal E(\mathbf k)|^2=|\mathbf k|^2 \sum_{\lambda = 1,2}|\mathbf \epsilon_\lambda(\mathbf k)\cdot\mathcal A(\mathbf k)|^2.$$